# Range error while sending form from html to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I created a form with jquery validator attached to it. You can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/5WMff/1329/

however, when I fill all the data and hit send button - instead of going to my php script (that only contains `echo "hey!!"`) I get the error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceededAc @ jquery.js:8436Ac @ (...) @ jquery.js:8437

Navigated to http://localhost/biz/pages/register.html?username=aaaaaa&company=aaaaaa&con…aa59605be32548df2535e5a9f9ceedb12d9666c6fb153ada99830ed5cd84eb0c2c4d00260a
```

What causes that? Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

I realized this block of code is causing the error:

```
var p = document.createElement("input");

// Add the new element to our form. 
form.appendChild(p);
p.name = "p";
p.type = "hidden";
p.value = "eevn now there's an error";//hex_sha512($("#password").val());
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you appended the html you need to get its reference again.
Try This -

```
var p = document.createElement("input");

// Add the new element to our form. 
p.name = "p";
p.type = "hidden";
p.value = "eevn now there's an error";//hex_sha512($("#password").val());
form.appendChild(p);
```